# How to determine input shape in keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I am having difficulty finding where my error is while building deep learning models, but I typically have issues when setting the input layer input shape.

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(1461, 75)),
Dense(32, activation='relu'),
Dense(ytrain.size),])
```

It is returning the following error:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3

 dimensions, but got array with shape (1461, 75)
```

The array is the training set from the kaggle housing price competition and my dataset has 75 columns and 1461 rows. My array is 2 dimensional, so why are 3 dimensions expected? I have tried adding a redundant 3rd dimension of 1 or flattening the array before the first dense layer but the error simply becomes:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected 

min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

How do you determine what the input size should be and why do the dimensions it expects seem so arbitrary?

For reference, I attached the rest of my code:

```
xtrain = pd.read_csv("pricetrain.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("pricetest.csv")
xtrain.fillna(xtrain.mean(), inplace=True)
xtrain.drop(["Alley"], axis=1, inplace=True)
xtrain.drop(["PoolQC"], axis=1, inplace=True)
xtrain.drop(["Fence"], axis=1, inplace=True)
xtrain.drop(["MiscFeature"], axis=1, inplace=True)
xtrain.drop(["PoolArea"], axis=1, inplace=True)
columns = list(xtrain)
for i in columns:
    if xtrain[i].dtypes == 'object':
        xtrain[i] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(xtrain[i])[0])
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for i in columns:
    if xtrain[i].dtypes == 'object':
        xtrain[i] = le.fit_transform(xtrain[i])
ytrain = xtrain["SalePrice"]
xtrain.drop(["SalePrice"], axis=1, inplace=True)
ytrain = ytrain.values
xtrain = xtrain.values
ytrain.astype("float32")

size = xtrain.size
print(ytrain)
model = Sequential(
    [Flatten(),
     Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(109575,)),
     Dense(32, activation='relu'),
     Dense(ytrain.size),
     ])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Any advice would be incredibly helpful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 0th dimension (sample-axis) is determined by the `batch_size` of the training. You omit it when defining the input shape. That makes sense since otherwise your model would be dependent on the *number of samples* in the dataset.

Same goes for the output. It seems you're only predicting a single value per example (`"SalePrice"`). So the output layer has shape 1.

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(75, )),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1),
])
```